# no muestra datos en div metodo jQuery post

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problema con jquery post, no muestra resultado que devuelve el ajax cuando envió los datos, estoy mostrando un mensaje de espera, el mensaje de espera si lo muestra cuando desparece el mensaje de espera se queda en blanco la ventana del navegador, este código es el que estoy usando

```js
            
            var cargando = $("#load").html("Por favor espere...");

            // evento ajax start
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                cargando.show();
            });

            // evento ajax stop
            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                cargando.hide();
            });

            $.post("procesaRenovacion.vbhtml", $('#envia').serialize(),
                    
                function (data) {
                    $('#muestraResultado').show();
                    $('#muestraResultado').html(data);
                });
```

el div donde deben aparecer los datos lo oculto cuando carga la pagina

```html
<div id="muestraResultado" style="display:none">Hola</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado el resultado de la petición POST? ¿Al ejecutarla en otra herramienta como RESTClient o soap-ui te devuelve los datos correctos? Quizás hay un problema durante la ejecución de la petición y el servidor devuelve una cadena vacía.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza apenas le implemente que muestre un mensaje si le quito lo del mensaje devuelve la información sin problemas

Comment: ¿Cuál es el formato de la información?

Comment: @fredyfx se puede delimitar a especificamente una función ajax

Comment: disculpa, tuve que borrar el comentario porque decidí incluirlo en la respuesta

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para entender tu problema concreto. El código tal como lo muestras debería funcionar sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucede que estas funciones aplican a todo AJAX que tengas:

```
// evento ajax start 
$(document).ajaxStart(function () { cargando.show(); }); 
// evento ajax stop 
$(document).ajaxStop(function () { cargando.hide(); });
```

Prueba con esto:

```
var cargando = $("#load").html("Por favor espere...");

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'procesaRenovacion.vbhtml',
data: $('#envia').serialize(),
beforeSend: function() {      
    cargando.show();  
},
success: function(data) {
  cargando.hide();
  $('#muestraResultado').show();
  $('#muestraResultado').html(data);
}});
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia en concreto? `$('#componente').html()` no es una llamada ajax. El código anterior debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Buena pregunta, para eso os invoco @Drago25, algo me dice que hay otras llamadas dentro de la pagina que no llegan a completarse, esta conclusión esta basada en la documentación de **jQuery** https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ y https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ En lo personal utilizo el **.ajax** con la función **beforeSend** para mostrar mensajes de carga/spinners.

Comment: hago otras llamadas a través de jQuery post para hacer otras funcionalidades, tal ves era por eso que no estaba visualizando el resultado

Comment: confirmado! ahorita ando al mismo estilo del Chapulin colorado: *Lo sospeche desde un principio* xD!!! hahahahaha!!! bueno mi estimado @Drago25 gracias por la aclaración y que siga la programación!!!

Comment: @fredyfx gracias bro por la ayuda

Comment: @Drago25 de nada bro, estamos para servir y seguir aprendiendo! la fuerza de la industria del desarrollo de software en la que estamos se basa en el compartir y aprender en conjunto. Saludos!